# How to produce ANOM_EXEC event in auditd journal?

Tags: executable, crash, linux-audit

I am using Ubuntu 16, and want to produce ANOM_EXEC event in auditd journal, like such i found in internet:

> type=ANOM_EXEC msg=audit(1222174623.498:608): user pid=12965 uid=1
> auid=2 ses=1 msg='op=PAM:unix_chkpwd acct="snap"
> exe="/sbin/unix_chkpwd" (hostname=?, addr=?, terminal=pts/0
> res=failed)'

But I am just find a way to produce ANOM_ABEND by calling:

```
kill -9 pid_of_my_process
```

Is there any ways to produce ANOM_EXEC?